# extract strings till ' \n ' character using lookbehnd in regex in python. And it can have alphanumeric characters, special characters and space also

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

text = '  My uncle is admitted in the hospital.\n He has been suffering from 10 months.\n The address of the hospital is \nApollo Health City Campus, Jubilee Hills, Hyderabad - 500 033. '

now i want to extract the address of the hospital i.e ' **Apollo Health City Campus, Jubilee Hills,** Hyderabad -** ' using regex lookbehind, i used the following code but i want a expression that can help me extract the strings uptill the \n character prior to the six digit pincode i.e '500 033'
Currently am trying to extract 6 strings but i want a regex expression that can help me get all the strings till '\n' .

```
r'((\w\S+\s+){1,6})(?=500 033)'
```

expected output - **' Apollo Health City Campus, Jubilee Hills, Hyderabad - '** i.e all strings before \n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not simply split using `\n` and get the last string?

```
text = ' My uncle is admitted in the hospital.\n He has been suffering from 10 months.\n The address of the hospital is \nApollo Health City Campus, Jubilee Hills, Hyderabad - 500 033. '
print(text.split('\n')[-1])
```

If you are sure that the string will contain a pincode. i.e 6 digit number, another approach could be:

```
text = ' My uncle is admitted in the hospital.\n He has been suffering from 10 months.\n The address of the hospital is \nApollo Health City Campus, Jubilee Hills, Hyderabad - 500 033. '
for x in text.split('\n'):
    if [idx.isdigit() for idx in x].count(True)==6:
        print(x)
```

I have added a check for 6 digit in a string only. you can modify according to your needs.

Comment: there can be more text after the line too, so that's not going to help. any other suggestions?

Comment: @guatidibba check Edit

Comment: the above solution of yours works well, but when the text = ' My uncle is admitted in the hospital.\n He has been suffering from 10 months.\n The address of the hospital is \nApollo Health City Campus, Jubilee Hills, Hyderabad - 500 033. India. Tel 2 +91-4023607777 Fax: +91-40-23608050\nE-mail : a;7uI|ohyd@apo{lchospita|s.I:om Website : www.apo|Iohospita|s.narn. www.apol|ohealthdty.oom Emeigency: 1066\n\n  '      the output is not obtained when text is updated.

Comment: This is because i have added a check where exactly 6 numbers should be matched in a sentence split by ```\n```. replace ```==6``` with ```>=6``` and it will work.